# iPhone Home Screen Web App and Staying Logged In

Tags: php, iphone, web-applications, local-storage, homescreen

I've been using PHP Session to stay logged in when I'm using a browser but when I save the web app to my Home Screen and launch the app, I have to Sign In each time I open up the app. Is there a way to stay signed in?

Could anyone supply an example of code or point me in the right direction as I looked into Local Storage and not sure how to set the LocalStorage value when I am Logged In and how to check the value exists.

NOTE: I currently use PHP to Sign In

Thanks

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $_SESSION['logged'];?> 
    <?php if ($_GET['logged'] == 1){?>
        $.cookie( 'loggedin', '1',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );
    <?php }?>
        if( $.cookie('loggedin') == '1' ) { 
            <?php $userlog = true?>
            $.cookie( 'loggedin', '1',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );
        } else {
            <?php $userlog = false?>
        $.cookie( 'loggedin', '0',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );        
        }
</script>
```

$_SESSION['logged'] is set from the sign-in.php file

**sign-in.php**

```
    if($count==1) {
        session_register("username");
        $_SESSION['logged']= $user;
        header("location: /?logged=1");
    } else {
        echo "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
```

Comment: No, actually you're 'not' using PHP to sign in. Not directly, at least. You're using iOS. What I mean to say by that: Store the login credentials in the app itself and have it 'reauthenticate' itself upon startup. That way, you can avoid signing in every time. I don't have code handy, which is why I only comment.

Comment: Give some snippet of your code and or application buddy poeples are guessing on your question over here.. :(

Comment: Have just editted to include my code

Comment: Setting cookies doesnt work either. I used jQuery Cookie and it doesnt work when I re-open the app

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you don't need LocalStorage.

Just set a cookie with an expiration in the future, rather than a session cookie (which is deleted when the browser closes).

You probably can't use PHP sessions for this since those are regularly deleted. Instead you have to handle the login cookie yourself.

Comment: No he might need to use `localstorage` because iphone home favorites clears the cookie after a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is problem but if sustainable local storage is what you want, to check if you were logged in, after you iOS APPLICATION get close then here it is:

set a flag to user default such as:

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"isLogin"];
```

then retrieve this value when application launch to check if u were logged in:

```
 BOOL isLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isLogin"];
```

Now perform what you need accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use LocalStorage which works fine